# How to count even numbers in the first n natural numbers?

Tags: functions

So let's say that I count $1,2,3,4$ and ask the question: How many even numbers are there  in this sequence. Well, there are $2$ even numbers or we can say $4/2$ even numbers. But if the count is $1,2,3$ then it is $3/2+1/2$. How can we write this in a single expression in the language of math?

Comment: $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ where $\lfloor \, \rfloor$ represents the floor function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commonest one is called the floor function, denoted by $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$, which is defined for all reals and returns the biggest possible integer that is not greater than the input value. For instance $\lfloor -0.9\rfloor=-1$,$\lfloor 2 \rfloor =2$, and $\lfloor 1.999\rfloor=1$ etc.

In your case, you want $f(n):=\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$.